# Achieving consistent card placement in responsive layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, web, sass, flexbox

I am currently working on a React project that involves displaying a set of cards inside a container. Each card has a fixed size of 231x237px. I have used flexbox for the layout of the cards. I want the number of columns to be even when moving a card to a new line. For example 2,4. Or 1 (on the smallest devices)

```
1 row: Card  - Card - Card - Card
```

or

```
1 row: Card - Card
2 row: Card - Card
```

[image: wrong displaying]

[image: correct]

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: Look into CSS grid and media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different take on your issue is using css grid to achieve your layout behaviour.

Apply grid on your main section:

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
</section>
```

Add CSS to the main div / section. Here you can specify the amount of columns @ grid-template-columns.

```
section {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

And break the template column on your pref width

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
  section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

See the working sample on [my codepen](https://codepen.io/wowpixels/pen/ExGjqzQ)